# noUiSlider pips and range

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I made a slider with noUiSlider.

Html:

```
<!-- Case 1 -->
<div class="slider">
  <div class="range" id="reach_range">900mm ~ 1,700mm</div>
  <div class="ui_slider" id="reachSlider">
    <!-- Slider -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Case 2 -->
<div class="slider case2">
  <div class="range" id="reach_range2">900mm ~ 1,700mm</div>
  <div class="ui_slider" id="reachSlider2">
    <!-- Slider -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
// Case 1
var range_rc_sliders = {
  'min': [900],
  '33%': [1200],
  '66%': [1500],
  'max': [1700]
};
var reachSlider = document.getElementById('reachSlider');
var reach = noUiSlider.create(reachSlider, {
  range: range_rc_sliders,
  start: [900, 1700],
  margin: 100,
  step: 100,
  connect: true,
  pips: {
    mode: 'range',
    density: 33,
    stepped: true
  },
});
reachSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  var from = Math.ceil(values[0]);
  var to = Math.floor(values[1]);

  var range = from + 'mm ~ ' + to + 'mm';
  $('#reach_range').text(range);
});


//case 2
var reachSlider2 = document.getElementById('reachSlider2');
var reach2 = noUiSlider.create(reachSlider2, {
  start: [900, 1700],
  margin: 100,
  step: 100,
  connect: true,
  range: {
    'min': 900,
    'max': 1700
  }
});
reachSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  var from = Math.ceil(values[0]);
  var to = Math.floor(values[1]);

  var range = from + 'mm ~ ' + to + 'mm';
  $('#reach_range').text(range);
});
```

In Case 1:
I set 'step: 100' so that it moves every '100mm'. However, it works within only 900~1200.
So... I changed it into Case 2, without pips. It perfectly works, but it doesn't show me the range below the slider.
Actually, I want to show the range under the slider, so I must use the pips, like Case 1.

Is there anyone who could help me? (p.s. I'm not good at English. Sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

The `step` you define in "case 1" only works between 900 and 1200 because you are using a "non-linear" slider. You can define the step for each sub-range to apply it everywhere:

```
// Case 1
var range_rc_sliders = {
  'min': [900, 100],
  '33%': [1200, 100],
  '66%': [1500, 100],
  'max': [1700]
};
```

Alternatively, you can set the `mode` for the `pips` option to `steps`: [documentation](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/pips/#section-steps).